# Rxdart package when used with google_sign_in or flutter_facebook_login is causing the flutter app to crash on startup

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

every time I try to rxdart package with google_sign_in or flutter_facebook_login my flutter app crashes on startup stating "unfortunately your_app has stopped".any leads would be helpful.

here is my flutter doctor summary

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    X Flutter plugin version 12.1 - the recommended minimum version is 16.0.0
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.29.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Any information about the crash like error output in the console?

Comment: That's the main problem, there were no errors in console when app crashes. Although the console keeps on processing normally like it would say..... syncing files with the mobile. I was also able to debug my code to some point but as soon as I would click **ok** on the alert in android device everything stops.

Comment: To get more information about the error, before you run app in flutter, in another shell or console run the command:

    adb logcat

Then run app,  when crash occurs see the console output for more information.